# Python3.x,pandas,csv,utf-8 error

Tags: python-3.x, csv, pandas, encoding, utf-8

I am trying to import a dataset using pandas and getting following error message:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 10: invalid start byte

I read about encoding and tried to use it as

```
df=pd.read_csv("file.csv",encoding="ISO-xxxx")
```

It showed error as invalid syntax.

I am sharing the link to my data if you guys want to have a look: https://www.kaggle.com/venkatramakrishnan/india-water-quality-data

Comment: Can you show the traceback of the "invalid syntax" error?

Comment: Please trim that dataset down to the smallest set of data that reproduces the problem, and then edit it into the question. If you delete the first half, or the second half, does the problem still happen? Can it be narrowed down to one line? Unless the problem can be shown in the question itself, the problem is off-topic, since we want the problem to be demonstrable well into the future (after you've deleted/modified the file externally).

Comment: invalid Syntax error is now removed , i check the traceback and solved it on my own.

Comment: latin1 worked for me well.

Comment: trimming the data set was producing the same error i tried it earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.read_csv('IndiaAffectedWaterQualityAreas.csv',encoding = 'latin-1')
```

The above code is one of the solution written in **python 3.6** and **pandas '0.20.1'**.

**why does this problem occur?**

> There are some special character which by default **utf-8** is cannot be used to
>   decode. if you have the raw data,try making the **csv** using pandas with
>   the following code:

```
df.to_csv('IndiaAffectedWaterQualityAreas.csv',encoding = 'latin-1')
```